# Не запускается игра(гонки)

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет! Прошу помочь, не запускается игра (гонки), все уже просмотрела, ошибок не выдает. Кнопка старт не срабатывает и машинки не двигаются. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

```js
var timer; // таймер
var cars; // массив картинок с машинками
var coordinates; // массив координат каждой машинки
var gameBegin; // переменная отвечающая за начало игры

var summa = prompt ("Введите вашу сумму");
var c = prompt ("На какую машину (от 0 до 4) будете ставить?");
var stavka = prompt ("Ваша ставка?");

// прописываем фукнцию go //
function go () {
    if (gameBegin == 1) return;
    gameBegin = 1; 
    cars = []; 
    for (var i=0; i < 4; i++) { 
        cars[i] = document.getElementById("car" + i);
        cars[i].style.border = none; 
    }
    // задаем координаты //
    coordinates = []; 
    for (i=0; i < 4; i++) { 
        coordinates[i] = 739; // все машинки начинают движение с точки 739рх справа
    }
    timer = window.setInterval(timerGo, 50); 
}

// прописываем функцию timerGo //
function timerGo() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        coordinates[i] = coordinates[i] - Math.floor((Math.random() * 7 +2));
        if (coordinates[i] <= 0) { 
            window.clearInterval(timer);
            gameBegin = 0;
            if (i == c) {
                alert ("You won!");
                summa += stavka;
            } else {
                alert ("Вы проиграли. До финиша доехала машина с номером " + i);
                summa -= stavka;
                alert ("Ваша сумма = " + summa);
            }
            cars[i].style.border = "5px ridge yellow";
            return;
        }
        cars[i].style.left = coordinates[i] + "px";
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id = "fon">
        <input type="button" onclick="go()" value="Start" >
        <img  id="car0" src="img/car0.png" alt="car">
        <img  id="car1" src="img/car1.png" alt="car">
        <img  id="car2" src="img/car2.png" alt="car">
        <img  id="car3" src="img/car3.png" alt="car">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Это все в одном файле? Оберни скрипты в тег <script> </script>

Comment: В разных, html и js. Здесь просто в одном выложила.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно было выставить position: relative для машинок. И `none` у вас была не строка при установке бордера.

```js
var timer; // таймер
var cars; // массив картинок с машинками
var coordinates; // массив координат каждой машинки
var gameBegin; // переменная отвечающая за начало игры

var summa = prompt("Введите вашу сумму");
var c = prompt("На какую машину (от 0 до 4) будете ставить?");
var stavka = prompt("Ваша ставка?");

// прописываем фукнцию go //
function go() {
  if (gameBegin == 1) return;
  gameBegin = 1;
  cars = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    cars[i] = document.getElementById("car" + i);
    cars[i].style.border = "none";
    cars[i].style.position = "relative";
  }
  // задаем координаты //
  coordinates = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    coordinates[i] = 739; // все машинки начинают движение с точки 739рх справа
    cars[i].style.left = coordinates[i];
  }
  timer = window.setInterval(timerGo, 50);
}

// прописываем функцию timerGo //
function timerGo() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    coordinates[i] = coordinates[i] - Math.floor((Math.random() * 7 + 2));
    if (coordinates[i] <= 0) {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
      gameBegin = 0;
      if (i == c) {
        alert("You won!");
        summa += stavka;
      } else {
        alert("Вы проиграли. До финиша доехала машина с номером " + i);
        summa -= stavka;
      }
      alert("Ваша сумма = " + summa); 
      cars[i].style.border = "5px ridge yellow";
      return;
    }
    cars[i].style.left = coordinates[i] + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
img { transform: scalex(-1); transition: left .05s linear; }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="fon">
    <input type="button" onclick="go()" value="Start">
    <img id="car0" src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-64/car-speed-travel-vehicle-high-29573.png" alt="car">
    <img id="car1" src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-64/car-speed-travel-vehicle-high-29573.png" alt="car">
    <img id="car2" src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-64/car-speed-travel-vehicle-high-29573.png" alt="car">
    <img id="car3" src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-64/car-speed-travel-vehicle-high-29573.png" alt="car">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: 7 раз сыграл — 7 раз проиграл! Требую исправления багов!

Comment: Это ерунда. Я пока тестировал - задолжал чтото около 2млн.

Comment: Добавьте в ваш ответ `img { transform: scalex(-1); transition: left .05s linear; }`

Comment: изи с первой попытки

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Ошибка была в отсутствии ковычек у none/   Relative - машинкам не понадобился, т.к. с ним они начинают ехать как-то криво)) Все заработало. Спасибо!!!